# VSC temporarily turn off yaml lintin

Tags: yaml, visual-studio-code

[image]

Trying to find a way to turn off the red lines temporarily for that file only.

Comment: Why does VSC even think that this it should apply YAML syntax checking, it clearly is not a YAML file based on content nor on filename extension (`.sls`)

Comment: You're right, it's not YAML syntax but the closest thing is YAML since saltstate syntax (yaml + jinja) isn't supported yet and no available plugins are available.  The reason why this .sls extensions reads as yaml is because of my filename_association set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try to disable the yaml.schemaStore ?

go in in settings.json and add :

```
"yaml.schemaStore.enable": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not valid YAML at all, but you want to edit this as YAML,
you should make it into valid YAML. If you turn of the errors,
instead you probably would not have all of the advantage of the YAML
editing mode.

If saltstate allows you to change the `block_start_string` and
`variable_start_string` jinja2 uses you can change `{%` into `#%` (or
`###%` if `#%` and `###%` naturally occur in your source), and also
change `{{` into `<{` (or `<<{`, you get the idea). If you would call
jinja2 directly you would then then pass to the `FireSystemLoader`:
`block_start_string='<{'` and `variable_start_string='#%'` If the
above is possible, then you have to change your input file only once,
do that with an editor.

If you cannot control saltstate to do the sane thing, your still not
stuck but you have to do a bit more using Python,
[`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) and some
support packages (disclaimer: I am the author of those packages).
Install with:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml[jinja2] ruamel.std.pathlib
```

Then before editing run the program:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path

yamlj2 = YAML(typ='jinja2')
yamlrt = YAML()
yaml_flow_style = YAML()
yaml_flow_style.default_flow_style = True

in_file = Path('init.sls')
backup_file = Path('init.sls.org')
in_file.copy(backup_file)

data = yamlj2.load(in_file)
with in_file.open('w') as fp:
    # write the header with info needed for revers
    fp.write('# ruamel.yaml.jinja2: ')  # no EOL
    yaml_flow_style.dump(yamlj2._plug_in_jinja2, fp)
    yamlrt.dump(data, fp)
```

which changes the offending jinja2 sequences and add a one-line header comment with the actual patterns used to the file. You should then be able
to edit the `init.sls` file without getting all those errors.

Before calling saltstate, do run the following:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path

in_file = Path('init.sls')
yamlj2 = YAML(typ='jinja2')
yamlrt = YAML()
yamlnort = YAML(typ='safe')
with in_file.open() as fp:
    yamlj2._plug_in_jinja2 = yamlnort.load(fp.readline().split(':', 1)[1])
    data = yamlrt.load(fp)
yamlj2.dump(data, in_file)
```

If you have multiple of these files, you probably want to take your
filename from sys.argv[1]. You might actually call the salstate program from this second Python program (i.e. decode and run).

Comment: Forgive me for being ignorant, I'm new to VSC.  I understand the python but I don't understand how this would work in VSC.

Comment: @MoAli This doesn't work **within** VSC, it makes the file correct YAML so when you open it with VSC it doesn't show the problems your posted image indicates. The only "problem" with that is that you have to make sure saltstate accepts the changes, or turn back those changes before starting saltstate. BTW are you sure you are using salstate and not [salststack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(software))

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm using saltstack.  The .sls files in salt are called saltstate hence saltstate.